# Setting timeout on webservice

Tags: java, web-services, timeout, settimeout

I am very new to webservices, I call a webservice through a wrapper provided by some party. I need to wait for certain amount of time after calling the webservice, if response is not received, i should shoot up time out response.

Remember i do not call the webservice directly. Below is the psuedo code.

```
String responseXML = pro.sendToCustomer("https://india.com/ClientGatewayV2/GatewayClientInterfaceV2", asaXML);
```

`pro.senToCustomer` is present in the jar provided by third party. How do i handle session time out on this?

Comment: Sorry but until u provide implementation detail of pro.sendToCustomer, we can't help. Either u can use custom httpclient and then add timeout option because its difficult to tell whehter this method supports timeout.

Comment: What is used behind your third party library? Axis? CXF? ...